# Finding if another vector is in the span of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm wondering if my reasoning is justified when determining if a vector is in the span of of a set of vectors.

$$T = \{(1, 1, 0), (-1, 3, 1)\}$$

For which $a$ is $(a^2, a+2, 2) \in span(T)$

I've come to the conclusion that there DNE an "$a$" which could make the vector be in the span of set $T$. However I'm not sure if my reasoning is justified.

For vector $V$ to be in the span of set $T$,it would have to be a linear combination of the two vectors in set $T$, a scalar of the vectors in set $T$, or combination of both.

In order to satisfy the $2$ in the third entry of vector $V$, we must have $2(-1,3,1)$. While we have our $2$ in the third entry, it does not fit the 1st and 2nd entries of vector $V$, so I would need add/subtract a scalar of the first vector $(1,1,0)$. But I've realized that it can never fit the requirements of vector $V$ so I've come to the conclusion that an "$a$" that would make vector $V$ to be in the span of set $T$ DNE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh yes, the answer should be $DNE$ if the $a$ must be real.

You mentioned that $T = \{(1, 1, 0), (-1, 3, 1)\}$ and the required vectors is $(a^2, a+2, 2)$. Assume there are real numbers $u, v$ such that $u(1, 1, 0) + v(-1, 3, 1) = (a^2, a + 2, 2)$, i.e. \begin{align}u - v &= a^2, \\ u + 3v &= a + 2, \\ v &= 2.\end{align}
Then it follows that $u = a - 4$ and the $1^{\text{st}}$ equation becomes $a^2 - a + 6 = 0$ which doesn't have a real solution.

And your thinking starts correctly. You just have to show (in case) how/why setting $u$ for whatever value won't makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the answer depends upen the field that you are working with. In fact,\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}a^2\\a+2\\2\end{bmatrix}\in\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}&\iff\begin{vmatrix}1&-1&a^2\\1&3&a+2\\0&1&2\end{vmatrix}=0\\&\iff a^2-a+6=0.\end{align}Over $\mathbb Q$, for instance, this equation has no solutions, whereas of $\mathbb C$, for instance, it has.